# Javascript console.log huge number

Tags: javascript

In javascript, why

```
console.log(99999999999999999)
```

results to

```
100000000000000000
```

TIA

Comment: See [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) which you exceed.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your number is too large for javascript.

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't handle number over **2^53 - 1** without rounding errors

see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

I suggest you use Strings for big numbers